# How to handle a @RequestParam not defined

Tags: java, spring, get-mapping

So, as the title says i have this piece of code here

```java
@GetMapping("/concat")
public String conc(@RequestParam("c1") String con1,@RequestParam("c2") String con2){
    return stringService.conc(con1, con2);
}
```

which just return a string concatenated  with another string. my problem here is, i want to NOT define the "c2" param and either says it's null or say nothing at all as it NEEDS to work with even just one param.

how do i achieve that?

i tried this

```java
@GetMapping("/concat")
public String conc(@RequestParam("c1") String con1,@RequestParam("c2") String con2){
    if(con2 == null){
        return con1;
    }else{
        return stringService.conc(con1, con2);
    }
}
```

it obviously didn't work and i don't know how to use `@ExceptionHandler` (if that is the solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a default value in `@RequestParam`: `@RequestParam(name = "yourParameterName", defaultValue = "yourParameterDefaultValue")`

Here, I just use an empty String as the default value:

```java
@GetMapping("/concat")
public String conc(@RequestParam("c1") String con1,@RequestParam(name="c2",defaultValue = "") String con2){
    return stringService.conc(con1, con2);
}
```

This will concatenate it with the empty string. Requesting `/concat?c1=a` will call `conc("a","")`.

Alternatively, you can use `required=false` and do an explicit null check:

```java
@GetMapping("/concat")
public String conc(@RequestParam("c1") String con1,@RequestParam(name = "c2", required = false) String con2){
    if(con2 == null){
        return con1;
    }else{
        return stringService.conc(con1, con2);
    }
}
```

Requesting `/concat?c1=a` will call `conc("a",null)`.

Comment: easiest and most efficient! that is great! didn't really knew you could have a "required" thing that's so much helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Set `required = false` in the annotation to make it optional.

```java
public String conc(@RequestParam("c1") String con1, 
                   @RequestParam(name = "c2", required = false) String con2){
    return stringService.conc(con1, con2 != null ? con2 : "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `required = false` as suggested, but you can also take advantage of [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) as follows:

```java
@GetMapping("/concat")
public String conc(@RequestParam("c1") String con1, @RequestParam("c2") Optional<String> con2){
    return con2.map(i->stringService.conc(con1, i)).orElse(con1);
}
```